# Self erasing workers c++

Tags: c++

Can anyone please explain me why this c++ code crashes (actually it doesn't crash instead valgrind complains about invalid memory access).

The idea is simple. Controler creates a few workers. Every worker gets functor object which erases this worker once it has done its job. Can anyone please present some solution?

```
typedef boost::function<void()> Callback;

struct Worker
{
    void start(Callback onFinnish)
    {
        // Called when finnished working
        onFinnish();
    }
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Worker> WorkerPtr;

struct Controler
{
    void start()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            auto workerPtr = boost::make_shared<Worker>();
            workers.insert(workerPtr);
        }

        for(const auto &workerPtr: workers)
        {
            workerPtr->start(
                [this, workerPtr] ()
                {
                    workers.erase(workerPtr);
                    if(workers.size() == 0)
                    {
                        std::cout << "All workers done!" << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }

    std::set<WorkerPtr> workers;
};

// Somewhere in code
Controler c; c.start();
```

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:**
I implemented the for auto loop like this and now it works:

```
    for(auto workerIt = workers.begin(); workerIt != workers.end();)
    {
        auto nextWorker = workerIt; ++nextWorker;

        (*workerIt)->start(
            [this, workerIt] ()
            {
                workers.erase(workerIt);
                if(workers.empty())
                {
                    onWorkersDone();
                }
            }
        );

        workerIt = nextWorker;
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what `workerPtr->start(...)` does? In particular, does this operation spawn a new thread? Depending on the answer of this question the problem is either a data race (if a thread is spawned) or iterator invalidation (if no thread is spawned).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Currently, OP provided an implementation of `workerPtr->start(...)` without threading (maybe by over simplification of his problem).

Comment: @Jarod42: er, true. In which case the problem is, indeed, the iterators being invalidated. Maybe time to restore parts of my original answer ;-) Thanks - somehow I didn't realize that `start()` is implemented!

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, you are right. Somehow I missed the fact that the `start()` function is there and doesn't start a thread. I would guess, however, that the problem was shifted from one to another problem when simplifying the code...

Answer (score 3):

In your for range, you modify the container inside the loop, which involves UB.

creating a copy of the set should fix your issue:

```
for(const auto &workerPtr: std::set<WorkerPtr>(workers)) // create a copy of the set
{
    workerPtr->start(
        [this, workerPtr] ()
        {
            workers.erase(workerPtr);
            if(workers.size() == 0)
            {
                std::cout << "All workers done!" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

**Edit:**
As noted by Dietmar Kühl, if your method `start` launches a new thread, then you will have data race on the `set`.

Answer (score 3):

According to 6.5.4 [stmt.ranged] the range-based for-loop behaves like this piece of code:

```
{
    auto && __range = workers;
    for (auto __begin = workers.begin(), __end = workers.end(); __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
        const auto& = *__begin;
        <body-of-the loop>
    }
 }
```

Since you happily blow away the objects currently being referred to, you actually invalidate the `__begin` iterator in each iteration of the loop: for associative containers all iterators and pointers/references to objects being erased are invalidated. Any invalidated iterators is a booby-trap waiting to be disarmed (by assignment or destruction) which will blow up in undefined behavior when used in any way other than disarming it.

Personally, I would fix the issue by iterating over the set and erasing its element in a more effective way anyway: your approach requires searching the elements in each iteration which is unnecessary cost. You can just keep an iterator:

```
for (auto it = works.begin(), end = works.end(); it != end; ) {
    (*it)->start([this, it]() {
         workers.erase(it++);
         if (workers.empty()) {
             std::cout << "All workers done!\n";
         }
     });
}
```

Of course, you should also use `container.empty()` to determine if the container is empty. ... and just don't use [`std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) as it doesn't do anybody any good. Use `std::flush` if you really mean to flush the stream.

Of course, if `start()` in the posted code is actually a simplification and actually starts a thread, the problem becomes a different one! In this case, the `erase()` statement isn't executed when the function object is being created to start the thread. The original issue, i.e., invaliding the iterators of the range-based `for` would only happen if the started thread executes and `erase()`d the object before the starting thread moved on!

Instead, there is an obvious data race: there are multiple thread `erase()`ing objects from `this->workers` without any synchronization at all! You can address the problem by guarding the access to the shared `std::set<WorkerPtr>` using a suitable mutex. For example, I think this code resolves the problem:

```
struct Controler
{
    void start()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            auto workerPtr = boost::make_shared<Worker>();
            this->workers.insert(workerPtr);
        }

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> kerberos(this->mutex);
        for(const auto &workerPtr: this->workers)
        {
            workerPtr->start(
                [this, workerPtr] ()
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> kerberos(this->mutex);
                    this->workers.erase(workerPtr);
                    if(this->workers.empty()) {
                        std::cout << "All workers done!\n";
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }

    std::set<WorkerPtr> workers;
    std::mutex          mutex;
};
```

Of course, the problem analysis and resolution assumes that `workerPtr->start(...)` actually starts a thread to do the work! If the work is executed on the same thread the iterators from the range-based `for` are, indeed, invalidated and adding a mutex as is done in the code above would cause a dead-lock.

Comment: But I really need to use this callback mechanism. Every worker must erase itself once its done. There is a single thread. Worker finnish its job immediately or it creates another callback which will be called later.

Comment: @piotrekg2: actually, you I'm convinced that there is _no_ such need! You may be better off redesigning your concurrency system to send suitable messages between actor objects. That is, instead of removing objects from a shared resource, you'd sent a suitable message to the object owning the shared resource and have it remove objects. Although I'm aware of various synchronization primitives, I'm generally not capable of using them correctly but I manage to get message passing system rights.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: as the OP's code doesn't use any thread (maybe due to over simplification), OP really modifies container during iteration... so my answer makes sense.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. It's true that there was a problem with invalidating iterator. I used raw iterators to solve this issue (increment before erasing).
@DietmarKühl I can't redesign the system (don't ask). I just have to stick with it. Generally the system works on a single thread and dispatches control to registered callbacks. If I want to synchronize things I have to create callback which registers another callback and so on.